# Event handler stops working in Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following line in one of my Angular controllers. The event handler fires every time when the initial page loads, but when navigating to a different item, even though they are using the same controller and template, it stops working.

```
        document.getElementById('item-details-view').addEventListener('touchstart', toggleshowoption, false);
```

UPDATE:

Trying with this directive:

```
app.directive('slideShowMenu', function () {
return {
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        var visible = false;

        function toggleshowoption() {
            if (!visible) {
                $(".slideshow-controls").css({"visibility": "visible", "opacity": "1"});
                visible = true;
            }
            else {
                $(".slideshow-controls").css({"visibility": "hidden", "opacity": "0"});
                visible = false;
            }
        }
        $element.addEventListener('touchstart', toggleshowoption, false);
    }
}
});
```

This gives me the following error:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating '$element.addEventListener('touchstart', toggleshowoption, false)')
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the event in a directive instead of outside the Angular workflow?

Comment: The #item-details-view change or you remake it? if you change (destroy) or you remake the #item-details-view you have to readd the eventListener, you can add this event to the global scope for all .item-details-view this way the event will fire in all the page even if change, or use jquery.on() ( i think angularjs use a lite version of jquery)

Comment: Nicearma - The template stays the same, but the content changes...so probably destroyed and remade.

Answer (score 0):

An element-id has to be unique - I suspect angular to render the template a second time thus creating two elements with the same id. Maybe using a class instead can help.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Same problem using getelementsbyclass...works on page load, not after navigation.

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?